# create paravirtualized domu using virt-manager

Tags: ubuntu, xen

When trying to create a paravirtualized domU using virt-manager I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 75, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/createvm.py", line 2089, in _do_async_install
    guest.installer_instance.start_install(guest, meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 542, in start_install
    domain = self._create_guest(
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 491, in _create_guest
    domain = self.conn.createXML(install_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 4034, in createXML
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed', conn=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: An error occurred, but the cause is unknown
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? I call virt-manager by entering "virt-manager" in terminal, the rest is done via the GUI. The environment is Ubuntu 20.04 and xen version 4.11.

Comment: what command exactly do you execute to get that error? What is your environment with versions? Provide more info than JUST the error..

Comment: @Ron Well I call virt-manager by entering "virt-manager" in terminal, the rest is done via the GUI. The environment is Ubuntu 20.04 and xen version 4.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'An error occurred, but the cause is unknown'

Anytime you see an error like that from libvirt it indicates an error reporting bug, so please report a bug with ubuntu.

The VM creation may be failing for legitimate reasons but it's tough to tell without libvirt reporting a good error